# file system choice pitfalls on 100TB volume

Tags: raid, storage, multipath-storage

I have an 84 disk *powervault* storage array, I have configured as a virtual (as opposed to linear) array, with the RAID method as *ADAPT* (versus linear array of raid-5 or raid-10.  One volume spans the entire array, and I have it showing up as `/dev/mpatha`.  The storage array is connected via scsi cable to host server running rhel-7.9.

Using the `gnome disks` gui I format that device using the **XFS** file system, and end up with 115TB of usable space, that I mount as `/data` to the powervault host server and then NFS expored and samba shared out, over 1gbps copper and 100gbps infiniband.

Realizing this sounds similar to a *what file system should I choose* question, given the above details is there a better file system choice over XFS out of what's available in RHEL 7.9 to choose from?  More importantly, in the future as this thing gets 50% full (50TB !) are there any foreseeable problems... what should I watch out for or specifically not do?  I do have a second identical powervault configured that will contain a backup copy of data on the first powervault.

Comment: As far as file system selection goes, see [big data + what is the right filesystem ext4 or xfs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440748/86440)

Comment: The EXT4 file system can support volumes with sizes up to 1 exbibyte (EiB) and single files with sizes up to 16 tebibytes (TiB) with the standard 4 KiB block size;  however the **operating system support is different**... Red Hat’s maximum supported size for Ext4 is 16TB in both Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, and 50TB in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. per redhat article 3129891 dated 9/4/2022.  So good thing I chose XFS.  Not sure what gnome disks would've done trying to format my 115tb volume as EXT4 under RHEL-7.9

Comment: Since you’re using RHEL, I’m assuming you care about having a supported system.

Comment: I stopped caring, rhel support is a joke