# Linux + is it correct to create volume using LVM over physical disks when disks size are huge

Tags: linux, lvm, disk, xfs, kafka

Our Goal is to use huge storage as 200TB for Kafka machine

In order to achieve this Goal , we create volume using LVM over 4 physical disks in RAID10 , when each disk size is 50T ,

**Note - each disk as sdb/sdc/sdd/sde is actually `RAID10` , when each RAID10 is holding 12 disks**

In our kafka server we have 4 disks ( example from `lsblk` )

```
sdb                  8:16   0   50T  0 disk 
sdc                  8:32   0   50T  0 disk 
sdd                  8:48   0   50T  0 disk 
sde                  8:64   0   50T  0 disk
```

So we wrote the following procedure:

We combine the disks `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. and `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sde` , by adding them to the same volume group.- `DB_vg`

```
vgcreate DB_vg /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
```

we create logical volumes  ( we are using here 200T size )

```
lvcreate -L200T -n DB_lv DB_vg
```

We create the XFS filesystem

```
mkfs.ext4  -j -m 0  /dev/DB_vg/DB_lv -F
```

We create folder , in order to mount the LV to this folder

```
mkdir /var/lib/kafka_broker

mount /dev/DB_vg/DB_lv /var/lib/kafka_broker
```

from `df -h` , its should looks like this ( example )

```
/dev/mapper/DB_vg-DB_lv  200T   61M  200T   1%  /var/lib/kafka_broker
```

from `lsblk`

```
sdb                   
└─DB_vg-DB_lv 253:4    
sdc                   
└─DB_vg-DB_lv 253:4   
sdd                  
└─DB_vg-DB_lv 253:4    
sde                  
└─DB_vg-DB_lv 253:4
```

from `blkid`

```
blkid | grep LVM2_member
/dev/sda2: UUID="Y5MbyB-C5NN-hcPA-wd9R-jmdI-02ML-W9qIiu" TYPE="LVM2_member"    <-- sda2 is the OS
/dev/sdc: UUID="mtg8CY-b3j9-K1qZ-CRTV-SZum-gDx3-lbm4ZX" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="MvfzqO-PV8N-dror-psl4-PfUf-7coa-6cb8lQ" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sdd: UUID="C4n63l-Uk3E-D65G-WcgI-xic2-cJLi-eSTUAa" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sde: UUID="d743Xp-eDxr-Dygk-HGgy-Dh9c-K3cx-kHtyqo" TYPE="LVM2_member"
```

So now we can use the LV `/dev/mapper/DB_vg-DB_lv` that mount to  `/var/lib/kafka_broker folder`

and we can use the folder  `/var/lib/kafka_broker` as storage with 200T for kafka broker machine

**My Questions are:**

1. is it safe? to use huge storage that created by LVM using 4 Huge disks?
2. can we create XFS filesystem when storage is around 200T size?
3. am I right about my procedure or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: The disks as sdb/sdc/sdd/sde are new scratch disks

Comment: in my procedure I not use pvcreate , shall I use it?

Comment: You need the `pvcreate` before you can create an LVM volume group. I suggest that if you've not tried this before, then you set up some (small) scratch disks. See the first part of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374665/100397)

Comment: ok, I accept your comment , second - do you think my Questions are reasonable enough?  , or I need to add some additional info ?

Comment: LVM used this way gives you one big filesystem, with zero load distribution. You can do that but I would prefer smaller volumes and let kafka itself handle the distribution. Kafka documentation even suggests letting it handle replication instead of relying on raid. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#diskandfs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As with any storage, this is as safe as your backups.
2. [XFS is supported up to 500TB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440750/86440), so this is fine.
3. As far as I can tell, nothing is missing (`vgcreate` and `vgextend` can initialize PVs, so you don’t need to run `pvcreate`).

Comment: another thing if I can, as already mentioned each disk is actually represented the RAID10 , do you see a problem with that? ( I asked this because Kafka service need high disk performance )

Comment: I answered your questions, taking all the information therein into account.

Comment: *If the devices were not previously intialized as PVs with pvcreate(8), vgcreate will inititialize them, making them PVs. The pvcreate
       options for initializing devices are also available with vgcreate.*

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wow, since October 2009! Thanks, I wasn’t aware of that!